# Read textfile with 2 value for each line in C

Tags: c, text, while-loop, scanf, eof

I'm trying to make a program that reads a textfile from stdin which has 2 values per line, eg 300 1941, 301 1942
One value is supposed to be assigned to a variable *adr*, the other is to be assigned to *instr*.
How would I make a function that opens the file, reads from beginning to EOF through a while loop and assigns these values to the variables through each iteration?

What I've done so far

```
void load_program(struct machine *m){

  unsigned int adr, instr;

  //something that iterates through the file and adds the values to the 
variables)
```

Comment: you added scanf as a tag, what have you tried with scanf ? Because that is viable approach

Comment: Yes scanf is something my teacher suggest, but I have no idea how it's supposed to work, especially as I don't know how to even use it to read the file

  while ( EOF != scanf("%x%x\n", &adr, &instr) )
    m->memory[adr] = instr;

Comment: Try [int reval = scanf("%d %d", &adr, &instr)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Comment: works like printf, except specifies input format. See @paulsm4 comment

Comment: How would this read the file though? I would have to open the file somehow. Would I need to use  fopen() then?

Comment: Use "redirection", e.g. `my_c_program.exe < myfile.txt`.

Comment: Thats a different issue. I would do a little research online before asking because that is a **very** common C task. Look into fopen

Comment: thanks paulsm4 but this has to be done as in within the program itself

Comment: see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) @Magniko

Comment: Thanks. I will try that
Just confusing that my teacher used scanf() instead

Answer (score 1):

In C, stdin is available via the global `stdin` file handle so there's no need to open a file separately.

To read pairs of integers from stdin you can simply use the [`fscanf(...)` function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), e.g.:

```
// pairs.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int addr, instr;
  while (fscanf(stdin, "%d %d", &addr, &instr) == 2) {
    printf("OK: addr=%d, instr=%d\n", addr, instr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can pipe or redirect files to the compiled program, for example:

```
$ echo -e "11 22\n33 44\n55 66" | ./pairs
OK: addr=11, instr=22
OK: addr=33, instr=44
OK: addr=55, instr=66

$ echo -e "111 222\n333 444\n555 666\n777 888" > input.txt
$ ./pairs < input.txt
OK: addr=111, instr=222
OK: addr=333, instr=444
OK: addr=555, instr=666
OK: addr=777, instr=888
```

Comment: oh, so you're saying that I can open the file already through a bash-script or in main, then just type in stdin on the fscanf() function?

Comment: Yes, all programs have three file handles automatically opened for them: stdin, stdout, and stderr. When you launch a program you can use special shell operators to "redirect" those streams to different files, if desired. And programs are free to open/close other files if they want and even re-open the standard streams to other files!